# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First Changes in Relationships often do not take

Tags: frameworks, entity-framework-4.1, entity, ef-code-first

I often get errors when running test cases after changing relationships. When checking the relationships on the data diagram I notice that they are often not reflecting any of the changes I did or only some of them, confusing the model. This only seems to be the case when creating the diagram within Server Explorer of Visual Studio.  When creating the diagram in SQL Server the changes show up fine.

Unfortunately, this also affects testing the code, because I'm never sure if a fails because of a problem with a change in the relationships I did or Visual Studio not updating. Having to detach and attach the database each time is a bit of a pain.

The database is dropped and recreated correctly, but Visual Studio seems to run the code against a cached version.  Had anybody else similar problems, any fix?

Answer (score 0):

I've certainly seen issues where I've updated SPs/function imports and tried to update the associated complex type, the dialog window says 'update', 'delete' etc next to the columns changed, so it's certainly seeing the different, but when applying the update these often don't seem to take and I end up manually adjusting the complex type.

In the above example I'm not sure whether the correct approach is to delete and recreate the type, but the existence of the update functions seem to suggest that an update should be possible. As you say mine too feels like a caching issue and whilst I've not yet found a solution I will be interested to see if you can find a solution, if I make any ground on this I will post back here too!

Comment: The only solution I found with this problem so far was to detach and re-attach the database in VS.  This usually fixes it but it's a real pain having to do this every time.  I tried having it only in SQL Server and just disconnect and reconnect it from there, but VS won't drop and generate the database until I come out completely from SQL Server, which is even worse.